# Deleted Database Still Shows in Object Explorer

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, ssms, azure-sql-managed-instance

In Azure managed instance: I have deleted database from SSMS using GUI and it showed success message as well. The deleted database does not show under Azure Portal as well

When reconnecting to the managed instance using SSMS, the database name shows in Object Explorer and not able to delete to do any activity with the same. Only name showing up with out any entries under it.

Can someone please assist with this.

Regards,
Kapil Jiri

Comment: how much time passed since you deleted the db?

Comment: Its been approx an hours its been deleted.

Comment: have you refreshed the object explorer since?

Comment: Yes. Refreshed, disconnect and reconnect as well.

Comment: For the best user experience with Azure Managed Instance please download SSMS 18, even if it is not at GA yet. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Unfortunately that does not help here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a candidate for opening support case. You might also try [this PowerShell cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Az.Sql/Get-AzSqlInstanceDatabase) to see if it shows your database.

If yes, you could try to delete it using the [following cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/remove-azsqlinstancedatabase).

Still, I would strongly advise opening the case with Msft to fix it permanently if there is something to fix.